# How to compare config changes between default branch and release branch mercurial

Tags: mercurial, comparison, configuration-files

Recently, we had few instances when developer failed to commit changes in default branch while working on another branch. This is specially with config files where a lot of settings are controlling the application. We are using beyond compare to compare files but with a massive amount of configs it is difficult to do a quick comparison of all configs. I am looking for something where we can compare and can pick up changes done in one branch and missed or removed from other.

Any held would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is it that the config files should look the same accross all your branches? Or do they also differ? Is there some means to assess whether changes are expected so that such thing can be scripted?

Comment: Yes, config files should look like same in all branches. I am looking for some tool that can parse all these files and prompt if it find any discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the config file in the default branch is always identical to the config file committed by a developer in any ohter branch, I suggest that you enforce this policy with a hook on the server which verifies that this task has been done and rejects the changesets if the config files differ. This is a comparatively easy task as long as you can rely on default branch having ever only a single head (probably a bad idea, though). However, then in bash the pretxnchangegroup hook for your server repository could look similar to:

```
hg_heads=`hg log -r"$HG_NODE:tip and head() and not branch('default")" --template='{node}\n'`
for hg_head in $hg_heads; do
  if [ "$(hg diff -r"head() and branch('default')" -r$hg_head CONFIGFILENAME)" != "" ]; then
    echo "Config files differ. Please make sure default has the same config file as your other heads!"
    exit 1
  fi
done
exit 0
```

It would reject all commits where a newly committed head has a different CONFIGFILENAME than the head of the default branch

As to checking your current repository, also do that via similar bash script which checks the diff for each head:

```
defaulthead=$(hg log -r"head() and branch('default')")
for head in $(hg log -r"head() and not branch('default')"); do
  if [ "$(hg diff -r$head -r$defaulthead)" != "" ]; then
    echo "Different config file for $head"
  fi
done
```